# Is this possible to modify python packages with python shell?

Tags: python, python-module, python-interactive

Let’s say I have a python package like this :

```
my-python-package/
    __init__.py
    app.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty and it is just for telling python that we have a python package. And `app.py` is this :

```
FAVORITE_COLORS = ['blue', 'purple']
```

Here is the idea, I want to append another color to this list using python shell. I started from changing directory, so we can simply import app.py :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('C:\Users\Javad\Desktop\my-python-package')
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\Javad\\Desktop\\my-python-package'
```

After that, We do our general task  :

```
>>> import app
>>> app.FAVORITE_COLORS
['blue', 'purple']
>>> app.FAVORITE_COLORS.append('red')
>>> app.FAVORITE_COLORS
['blue', 'purple', 'red']
```

According to what we see in python shell, ‘red’ successfully appended to the app.FAVORITE_COLORS. But when you open app.py, it’s exactly the same before modify :

```
FAVORITE_COLORS = ['blue', 'purple']
```

I would be appreciated if someone explains what’s happened. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to explain complete but if you need further information leave a comment please.

Comment: You load app.  You can modify your app attributes, but you aren't doing anything to the file where app was loaded from

Comment: @joelgoldstick what is the solution ?

Comment: @Uncle no you can't do that.

Comment: @wind85 why ? always must be a way!

Comment: @Uncle of course there is a way, but you can't do that with an import statement, you shuold serialize and deserialize the file you modify or class. Have a look at the pickle https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html.

Comment: I would be appreciated if the other guys share their opinion too.